Where is the kernel entry point?
I am studying the Linux kernel.
Where is the kernel entry point?
I am using a 64-bit UEFI PC with Ubuntu.
/arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.S
Is the entry point startup_32 in head_64.S correct?
If the kernel is set to 64-bit, does that mean it is running in 32-bit in grub2?
Also, are there any boot loaders whose entry point is startup_64?
Thanks in advance.

I’m voting to close this question because AskUbuntu is not a tutorial site.
